# Show alert after dismissing presentingviewController

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, uialertcontroller

When a user purchased `completion handler` notify me and dismiss `viewController`. However, I want to display/show an `alert` to the user after `viewController` dismissed. At the moment when I step through in the debugger, it goes through the code but the alert isn't being shown. Still getting inbuilt in apple one that says `All set`. Is there a way I can display my alert after dismissing the `viewController`.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ pAnimated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(pAnimated)
    self.notifyForUserHasPurchasedProduct {
        self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            UIAlertController.bs_showAlertFrom(self, title: "AppName", message: "Thank you. Your purchase was successful")
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `self.present(alert, animated: true)` to show alert. When `ViewController` `self` is not present, you need to change code to `presentedViewController.present(alert, animated: true)`

I have builded some functions:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func topMostViewController() -> UIViewController {

        if let presented = self.presentedViewController {
            return presented.topMostViewController()
        }

        if let navigation = self as? UINavigationController {
            return navigation.visibleViewController?.topMostViewController() ?? navigation
        }

        if let tab = self as? UITabBarController {
            return tab.selectedViewController?.topMostViewController() ?? tab
        }

        return self
    }
}

func getRootController () -> UIViewController { // function in global scope
    return (UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!!.rootViewController)!
}
```

And then use them like here:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ pAnimated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(pAnimated)
    self.notifyForUserHasPurchasedProduct {
        self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "AppName", message: "Thank you. Your purchase was successful", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let topC = getRootController().topMostViewController()
        topC.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I create an alert in an extension then just it there. I don't see the difference between my code and yours. You create an `alertController` object and i also do that in a extension where i call it in this `viewController`

Comment: Ok. You need to find presented on screen controller and call `presentedViewController.present(alert, animated: true)`

Comment: You forgot to call `self` on `getRootController().topMostViewController()`. Should be `self.getRootController().topMostViewController()`. Since you are in this current `ViewController`

Comment: dont use `self` there. Move getRootController() to global or make static function in some class. Here I place on global scope

Comment: Could you tell me why please?

Comment: This function works getRootController() doesnt use specified controller. You better move this method to an extension of `AppDelegate` and set it `static`. And than you can call `AppDelegate.getRootController()` anywhere, even from custom views